# How to show data from sql table to make one of columns value column header(date)

Tags: mysql, select

Hello I have 2 tables in mysql DB:

```
mysql> describe lvlsupdate;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| LvlsUpdateId | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| UID          | int         | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                   |
| Nick         | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| date         | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| Lvl          | int         | YES  |     | NULL              |                   |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
5 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> describe players;
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| UID    | int         | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Nick   | varchar(30) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| Active | tinyint(1)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

In one of theme there is column date which includes timestamp value.
I'd like to create query that will show me data that there will be column Nick and 7 dates (today and 6 days before). And in each row there should be nick and lvl value from each of this dates in proper column.

For now, I've created query like this:

```
SELECT LvlsUpdate.nick, LvlsUpdate.lvl, LvlsUpdate.date 
FROM LvlsUpdate 
INNER JOIN Players ON LvlsUpdate.uid = Players.uid 
WHERE Players.active = 1 AND LvlsUpdate.date > date_sub(now(), interval 7 day)
```

which shows me list of nicks, lvls, and date but there are duplicates of nicks, it looks like this:

```
+------------------+------+---------------------+
| nick             | lvl  | date                |
+------------------+------+---------------------+
| Player1          |  124 | 2020-10-11 00:01:02 |
| Player1          |  125 | 2020-10-12 00:01:03 |
| Player1          |  125 | 2020-10-13 00:01:02 |
| Player2          |  233 | 2020-10-11 00:01:02 |
| Player2          |  233 | 2020-10-12 00:01:03 |
| Player2          |  233 | 2020-10-13 00:01:02 |
| Player3          |  164 | 2020-10-11 00:01:02 |
| Player3          |  164 | 2020-10-12 00:01:03 |
| etc....
```

There is reference between LvlsUpdate.UID and Players.UID. There is only 1 entry per player per day.

Is it possible to do it in sql?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to display. Can you add another table below your current output to show your expected output?

Comment: @ThomasF Id like to get something like this: imgur.com/a/kPt2ZVu